# Why does GCC complain about conversion from `void**` to `const void**`?

Tags: c, gcc, implicit-conversion, gcc-warning

I'm just wondering why I get a warning for this code:

```
void example(const int** x) {
    // whatever
}

int main() {
    int** x;
    example(x);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC's output:

```
$ gcc example.cpp
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:9:14: error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘const int**’ [-fpermissive]
     example(x);
              ^
example.cpp:1:6: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘void example(const int**)’
 void example(const int** x)
      ^
```

What's wrong with converting from `int**` to `const int**`? Shouldn't this always be safe?

Also, why is the above code bad, but this code is fine?

```
void example(const int* x) {
    // whatever
}

int main() {
    int* x;
    example(x);
    return 0;
}
```

My original code used `struct mytype**` and had the same warning, so I assume it doesn't matter what the type is. Is this a case of reading C types wrong?

Comment: [Seems to work fine when I try it.](http://ideone.com/IEOTAb) Ideone says it's using GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: why did you put `void **` in the title but `int **` in the question body?

Comment: @user2357112 the code is illegal; activate the compiler in standard mode instead (not sure if that is possible with ideone)

Comment: @MattMcNabb As I mentioned, later on, it doesn't matter what type it is.